# How to set 'email' in author_id inherit mail.thread on Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, message

I inherit `mail.thread` on Odoo12

```
_inherit = ['mail.thread', 'mail.activity.mixin']
```

and publish a message:

```
msg = 'message test.'
self.message_post(body=msg, email_from='Otro <otro@otro.com>', subtype='mail.mt_comment',)
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GEHY.png)

These messages are added with the administrator user. How can I place the mail of the external user who sends the message in the field `author_id`?

Comment: Could you provide the surrounding code? It could be possible that you use `sudo()` anywhere, which is changing the environment user to admin. And you're not providing an `author_id` for `message_post()` which will make Odoo take the environment user as author.

Comment: @CZoellner that's the question, how to set author_id = 'other@otro.com' ... what I understand is that author_id expects an id but the author of this message is not in the odoo database.

Comment: Try out `self.message_post(body=msg, email_from='Otro <otro@otro.com>', subtype='mail.mt_comment', author_id=False)`

Comment: @CZoellner ... Oh thanks! that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out `self.message_post(body=msg, email_from='Otro <otro@otro.com>', subtype='mail.mt_comment', author_id=False)`

`author_id=False` will tell Odoo to use the `email_from` as author.

I've found that "trick" here:

```py
    author_id = kwargs.get('author_id')
    if author_id is None:  # keep False values
        author_id = self.env['mail.message']._get_default_author().id
```

The semi-valuable comment `# keep False values` solved the big secret ;-)

With `None` the user of the current environment would be used.